# How do I hide the li's that don't fit on a single line?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a ul with product information as li's. What I want to do is hide the li's that don't fit on a single line based on screen size.

So the number of products displaying should increase or decrease based on how many fit on a single line. This in turn depends on the users screen size.

Here's what I would like it to look like:

[image]

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

How do I accomplish this? Could I do this in plain HTML/CSS or do I need to use JS/JQuery?

**JSFiddel**:

http://jsfiddle.net/narzero/5v3jL4wx/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="content_panel active">
    <ul class="unstyled items_board">

      <!-- AARDAPPEL - GROENTE - FRUIT -->
      <li class="item_header">AARDAPPEL - GROENTE - FRUIT</li>
      <!-- One -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/6KJFwk" alt="One">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€2.03</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">Aarts Frambozen op siroop</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">370 ml</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Two -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/A4IzmQ" alt="Two">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€2.63</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardappelen iets kruimig</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">3 kg</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Three -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/CpPGvi" alt="Three">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€3.47</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardappelen iets kruimig voordeelzak</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">5 kg</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Four -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/VhbPh9" alt="Four">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€1.48</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardappelpartjes</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">450 gr</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Five -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/bzQua4" alt="Five">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€2.03</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardappelschijfjes spek en ui</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">500 gr</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Six -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/3CkHGK" alt="Six">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€2.39</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardbeien</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">250 gr</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <!-- BAKKERIJ -->
      <li class="item_header">BAKKERIJ</li>
      <!-- One -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/Ca4snB" alt="One">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€5.99</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardbeien bavaroise vlaai half</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">per stuk</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Two -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/FCJCqU" alt="Two">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€5.99</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Aardbeienslof</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">per stuk</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Three -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/wl7yYI" alt="Three">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€3.59</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Abrikozenvlaai half</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">per stuk</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Four -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/j3JZBP" alt="Four">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€0.94</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Allinson volkoren half</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">per stuk</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Five -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/KJzJuq" alt="Five">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€4.79</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Appel-abrikozentaartje</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">per stuk</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Six -->
      <li class="item ">
        <div class="media">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/Lx2YMo" alt="Six">
          <div class="info_group">
            <span class="price_info"><button class="btn btn_price">€6.59</button></span>
            <span class="add_button"><button class="btn btn_success">Add</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <div class="item_name item_row">
            <span class="full_item_name">AH Appelkruimelvlaai</span>
            <span class="item_size muted">per stuk</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*==== Content panel ====*/
.content_panel .active {
  display: inherit;
}

/*==== Product grid ====*/
.unstyled {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

li {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul > .unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.items_board {
  padding: 4px;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.item_header {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  cursor: auto;
  border: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.item_header:first-child {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.items_board > .item {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 205px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #e5edec;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*==== Single product ====*/

/* Media */
.items_board .item:hover .media {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.items_board .item .media {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
}

/* Info Group */
.info_group {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  display: none;
  width: 185px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5edec;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.75), #fff);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
}

.price_info {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  filter: alpha(opacity=85);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: .85;
  float: left;
}

.add_button {
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 0;
  float: right;
}

.item:hover .info_group {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn_success {
color: #fff;
background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.btn_price {
  color: white;
  background-color: #929292;
}

.btn_success:hover,
.btn_success:focus,
.btn_success.focus,
.btn_success:active,
.btn_success.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #449d44;
}

/* Item info */
.item_info {
  padding: 10px 25px 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 61px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.item_name {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.item_row {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.full_item_name {
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.muted {
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
```

Comment: what about css `overflow: hidden` or in your case `overflow-x: scroll`?

Comment: On what element? I've tried it on ul and li without success.

Comment: you have to use it on the container `parent div` `.content_panel{ overflow-x: scroll;}`

Comment: It's not working, here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/narzero/9Ljj1yvc/

Comment: i see, you might have a lil building problem... ill have a look and brb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an option to split the list in two `<ul> ... </ul>` one for each category then you could use `overflow: hidden;`

```
ul {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5v3jL4wx/1/

Answer (score 1):

I added a ul and ended the first on.

Also did some css changes and here is the result

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fkabyxp8/)**

```
 .unstyled {
    font-size: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

as you can see i added a `overflow-x: scroll;` so you can scroll left or right to see the rest. Also i added a `white-space: nowrap;` to keep the line in one row.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood the question. I want the products that don't fit on the screen to be hidden, like emmanuel's example here http://jsfiddle.net/5v3jL4wx/1/.

Comment: @narzero i understood you, thats why i had a `overflow: hidden;` in my first comment.